# Assigning Custom Azure AD Role to a Security Group

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've created a custom Azure AD role for the purpose of reading service principals within the directory.  This is so users can troubleshoot without needing to find additional support.  However, I'm not able to assign this custom role to an entire security group.  How can I assign this role to all users within a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the powershell to assign this role to all users in this group, try the script below.

First, you need to install the [`AzureADPreview`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.2.77) powershell module.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview
```

---

```
Connect-AzureAD

$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "<ObjectId of the Security Group>"
$roleDefinition = Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -Filter "displayName eq '<Custom role name>'"

# Get app registration and construct resource scope for assignment.
$appRegistration = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "displayName eq 'joyttt'"
$resourceScope = '/' + $appRegistration.objectId

foreach($member in $members){
    New-AzureADMSRoleAssignment -DirectoryScopeId $resourceScope -RoleDefinitionId $roleDefinition.Id -PrincipalId $member.ObjectId
}
```

[image]

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-create-custom#assign-the-custom-role-using-azure-ad-powershell

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I use the Azure AD powershell module all the time but had not considered using this method to assign roles.  Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: @ekbrothers Note it is `AzureADPreview` module, it is different from `AzureAD` module, if you have installed `AzureAD` module, please uninstall the `AzureAD` module first, with `Uninstall-Module -Name AzureAD`, then install the `AzureADPreview` module.